# windows phone emulator of visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

my windows phone emulator on visual studio 2010 does not work. what to do?

> windows phone emulator is not supported on this computer because this computer
>   does not have the required graphics processing unit configuration. An XNA Framework game or page will not function without a graphics processing unit.
>   A Silverlight application may run,but with reduced functionality. Do you want to continue starting the emulator?

If I click 'no' it shows error message as invalid command line args.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Please read this first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then edit your question.

Comment: What if you click 'yes'?

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna the emulator opens up but it does not load the app.

Comment: @DhanukaLakshan My emulator is not running the app, this is what is my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error, it sounds like you don't meet the minimum hardware requirements to run the Windows Phone Emulator. I suggest checking your GPU and making sure the OS can see it (ie. Open Device Manager -> Expand 'Display adapters' -> Check what is listed beneath. Chances are you don't meet the requirements as mentioned before. If so, you will either need to get a GPU that meets the requirements, or test on a physical device (as in, not in the emulator). Hope this helps.

Comment: I have Wddm 1.0 and have tried updating it to wddm 1.1 too but it shows the error that system requirements do not allow installation. I do not know what are the requirements for installing wddm 1.1. Can you please help while I am trying the device.

Comment: First, can you list the hardware on your device? Specifically graphics card (if not embedded) and processor?